# Not able to view multi-level data in treeview

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have json data with nested levels and want to represent using kendo TreeView.
However, I tried different schemas but not able to represent this data in tree view. Any suggestions

```
{
   "Level1":[
      {
         "id":"idlevel1",
         "name":"Level1",
         "Level2":[
            {
               "id":"idlevel2",
               "name":"Level2",
               "Level3":[
                  {
                     "id":"id1level3",
                     "name":"Level3_1",
                     "Level4":[
                        {
                           "id":"id1level4",
                           "name":"1_level4"
                        },
                        {
                           "id":"id2level4",
                           "name":"2_level4"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "id":"id2level3",
                     "name":"Level3_2",
                     "Level4":[
                        {
                           "id":"id1level4",
                           "name":"1_level4"
                        },
                        {
                           "id":"id2level4",
                           "name":"2_level4"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is my schema

```
 schema:{
                  data: "Level1",
                  model:{
                        children:{
                              schema:{
                                    data:"Level2",
                                    model:{
                                          children:{
                                                schema:{
                                                      data:"Level3",
                                                      model:{
                                                            children:{
                                                                  schema:{
                                                                        data:"Level4"
                                                                  }
                                                            }
                                                      }
                                                }
                                          }
                                    }
                              }
                        }
                  }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using [`HierarchicalDataSource`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/hierarchicaldatasource) ? I've just copy-pasted your code into a treeview code and it worked:

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
        dataTextField: "name",
        dataSource: new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
          data: data,
          schema:{
                  data: "Level1",
                  model:{
                        children:{
                              schema:{
                                    data:"Level2",
                                    model:{
                                          children:{
                                                schema:{
                                                      data:"Level3",
                                                      model:{
                                                            children:{
                                                                  schema:{
                                                                        data:"Level4"
                                                                  }
                                                            }
                                                      }
                                                }
                                          }
                                    }
                              }
                        }
                  }
            } 
        })
});
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/iMESUBiN)

Comment: oh nice..I did not use HierarchicalDataSource earlier